# User defined int class that supports addition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to  create a class that wraps an `int` and allows some things not normally allowed with `int` types. Here is my code:

```
class tInt(int):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if type(other) == str:
            return str(self) + str(other)
        elif type(other) == int:
            return int(self) + other
        elif type(other) == float:
            return float(self) + float(other)
        else:
            return self + other
a = tInt(2)
print (a + "5")
print ("5" + a)
```

The output was:

```
25
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\example.py", line 14, in <module>
    print ("5" + a)
TypeError: Can't convert 'tInt' object to str implicitly
```

So, the first print statement ran nicely, and gave what I expected, but the second one gave an error. I think this is because the first one is using `tInt.__add__` because `a` appeared before `+ "5"` and the second one is using `str.__add__` because `"5"` appeared first. I know this but I don't really know how to either force `a.__add__` to be used or allow the `tInt` class to be represented as a string/int/etc. when a normal type appears before it in an operation.

Comment: The `else` clause will cause infinite recursion. `self + other` will call `self.__add__(other)` again.

Comment: Damn, I didn't think of that. So I should sort of "sanitize" all my other ones by making sure self is a different type?

Comment: Use `return NotImplemented` instead. This will instruct Python to either try `tInt.__radd__(other)` if it is defined, or to try `type(other).__add__(self)` if not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to implement an `__radd__` method to handle the case when an instance of your class is on the right hand side of the addition.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) say:

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations
> (+, -, *, @, /, //, %, divmod(), pow(), **, <<, >>, &, ^, |) with
> reflected (swapped) operands. These functions are only called if the
> left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the
> operands are of different types. For instance, to evaluate the
> expression `x - y`, where `y` is an instance of a class that has an
> `__rsub__()` method, `y.__rsub__(x)` is called if `x.__sub__(y)` returns `NotImplemented`.

Example:

```
class tInt(int):

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return str(self) + str(other)
        elif isinstance(other, int):
            return int(self) + other
        elif isinstance(other, float):
            return float(self) + float(other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other) 

a = tInt(2)
for x in ["5", 5, 5.0]:
    print(a + x)
    print(x + a)
    print()
```

```
25
25

7
7

7.0
7.0
```

As @chepner pointed out in the comments, returning [NotImplemented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=notimplemented#NotImplemented) for cases that your method doesn't handle will cause Python to try other ways of performing the operation, or raise a TypeError if there is no way to perform the requested operation.

In the above code, the implementation of `__radd__` is trivial because integer addition is *associative*, that is

```
2 + 3 == 3 + 2
```

Addition of other types may not be associative, in which case `__radd__` will need to do more than just delegate to `__add__`:

```
'a' + 'b' != 'b' + 'a'
[0, 1] + [2, 3] != [2, 3] + [0, 1]
```