# How to properly overload the __add__ method?

Tags: python, class, overloading

I am required to write a class involving dates. I am supposed to overload the `+` operator to allow days being added to dates. To explain how it works: A `Date` object is represented as (2016, 4, 15) in the format (year, month, date). Adding integer 10 to this should yield (2016, 4, 25). The `Date` class has values `self.year`, `self.month`, `self.day`.

My problem is that the code is supposed to work in the form `Date + 10` as well as `10 + Date`. Also `Date - 1` should work in the sense of adding a negative number of days. `Date(2016, 4, 25) - 1` returns `Date(2016, 4, 24)`.

My code works perfectly in the form of `Date + 10` but not in the form `10 + D` or `D - 1`.

```
def __add__(self,value):
    if type(self) != int and type(self) != Date or (type(value) != int and type(value) != Date):
        raise TypeError
    if type(self) == Date:
        day = self.day
        month = self.month
        year = self.year
        value = value
    if type(value) != int:
        raise TypeError
    days_to_add = value
    while days_to_add > 0:
        day+=1
        if day == Date.days_in(year,month):
            month+=1
            if month > 12:
                day = 0
                month = 1
                year+=1
            day = 0
        days_to_add -=1
    return(Date(year,month,day))
```

These are the errors I get

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Date'`

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Date' and 'int'`

Comment: You need to implement `__radd__` as well.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36745772/5320906.  Subtraction is a separate operation for which you'll need to implement `__sub__` and `__rsub__` methods.

Comment: I see. So if my professor instructs me to "overload the + operator" he automatically means to create all these methods? Or to put it another way, overloading is defined by doing all these methods?

Comment: Yes, generally "overloading an operator" means extending or overriding the behaviour of operator such as + or -.  To do this you need to override the associated special methods - cf the answer I referred you too earlier.  We can't tell you what your professor means though, you'll need to ask them.

Comment: Is your Date class stand-alone, or are you permitted to use stuff  from the standard datetime module?

Answer (score 20):

[`__radd__`](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php) handles right side addition so you need to implement that as well.

I am seeing some flaws in your implementation so I recommend you using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module *(especially **datetime.timedelta** class)* to at least handle basic date arithmetic correctly:

```
import datetime

class Date(object):
    def __init__(self, year, month, day):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day

    def as_date(self):
        return datetime.date(self.year, self.month, self.day)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int):
            date = self.as_date() + datetime.timedelta(days=other)
            return Date(date.year, date.month, date.day)
        else:
            raise ValueError("int value is required")

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(-other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        raise RuntimeError("Doesn't make sense.")

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.as_date())
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> date = Date(2015, 10, 23)
>>> print date + 10 # __add__ is called
2015-11-02

>>> print 20 + date # __radd__ is called
2015-11-12

>>> print date - 25 # __sub__ is called
2015-09-28

>>> print 25 - date # __rsub__ is called 
RuntimeError: Doesn't make sense
```