# unsupported operand type error when adding objects within list using sum function

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, addition, series

I have a `Serie` class implemented to represent series of data and it's tag. When I add `Serie` objects and also numbers I get the expected output. However when I sum the same elements within a list I get following error message:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Serie'

### Toy example code

As a toy example code to understand the problem we can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class Serie(object):

    def __str__(self):

        s = "> SERIE " + str(self.tag) + ": \n"
        s += str(self.data)
        return s

    def __init__(self, tag=None, data=pd.DataFrame()):
        """
        Creates object Serie

        @type tag: str
        @param tag: Tag for the Serie
        """
        self.tag = tag
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            tag = str(other) + "+" + self.tag
            serie = Serie(tag)
            serie.data = self.data + other
        else:
            try:
                tag = self.tag + "+" + other.tag
            except:
                print ("ERROR: You can't add to somehing that is not a Serie or a number." )
                return None
            serie = Serie(tag)
            serie.data = self.data + other.data
        return serie

s1 = Serie("fibonacci",pd.Series([1,1,2,3,5,8]))
s2 = Serie("2power",pd.Series(np.linspace(1,6,6)**2))
s3 = 10
sumSerie = s1+s2+s3
print sumSerie
```

This prints the result as expected:

```
>>> 
> SERIE 10+fibonacci+2power: 
0    12.0
1    15.0
2    21.0
3    29.0
4    40.0
5    54.0
dtype: float64
```

### Error when using sum of objects within list

However when I run following lines:

```
l = [s1,s2,s3]
sum(l)
```

I get error message:

> sum(l) 
>   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Serie'

And same error message is displayed when I run:

```
l2 = [s1,s2]
sum(l2)
```

But in `l2` list there is no `int` variable.

### Questions

Why is this error message being displayed? This is confusing as I was able to sum the objects outside the list.

Is there something I can do in order to achieve performing the sum of the objects within the list?

## EDIT

As suggested in the comments, I added the `__radd__` to correctly overload the add method. So I added the below lines to the `Serie` class:

```
def __radd__(self,other):
    return self.__add__(other)
```

Then the sum works. But not as expected.

If I run the below code:

```
>>> print sum(l)
```

I get this output:

```
> SERIE 10+0+fibonacci+2power: 
0    12.0
1    15.0
2    21.0
3    29.0
4    40.0
5    54.0
dtype: float64
```

Which is definitely not the same I expected. There is a `+0` extra within the tag. How can this be? However if I use the option I stated in my answer `print np.array(l).sum()` the result is correct.

## EDIT 2

After overloading add method correctly I was suggested to use below method to perform the sum as expected:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, l)
```

This approach worked to be able to use `sum` function for the list and get the correct result.

As stated by [pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault) in the comments in `sum` method "start defaults to 0" as detailed in [sum function's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum). That was why the extra `+0` was being added to the tag before.

In conclusion I believe I would preferrably use the option using `numpy.sum` function instead:

```
np.array(l).sum()
```

Comment: I implemented this on `python 2.7` and `python 3.5` and got same results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly overload the \_\_add\_\_ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785417/how-to-properly-overload-the-add-method)

Comment: You need to implement `__radd__` as well. While `s2+s3` works for you currently, you will see that `s3+s2` will not.

Comment: Thanks @pault, this acomplishes one of the issues. But the output is not the same as the one I expect. And I believe this is definitely not a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785417/how-to-properly-overload-the-add-method)

Comment: That is because as stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) you linked *"start defaults to 0"*. Try: `reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, l)` (or use `operator.add` instead of the `lambda`).

Comment: Thanks @pault. Using `reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, l)` did the trick. However I think I would go for using `np.array(l).sum()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why using the sum function is not possible. But a workaround to get the desired output from the lists would be to create a `numpy` array from the list and use `numpy.sum` function as you can see below:

```
np.array(l).sum()
```

This gives the sum of the objects from the list as expected.

Comment: I would still like to know why the `sum(l)` is not possible. I guess it's the same reason why you can't do something like `sum(["a","b"])` as explained in [sum function's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).