# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'Time'

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I'm trying to get this to work, it seems like the problem is when I try to add an hour and a decimal representing time (ex. .75 equating to 45min). I think I need to add something to the **init**() however, I'm not sure what would solve it. A float?

```
class Time():

    def __init__(self,a=0.0,b=0.0):
        self.hour = a
        self.minute = b
        self.hour_dec = a-int(a)
        self.total_hour = self.hour - self.hour_dec
        self.extraMin = self.hour_dec * 60
        self.total_min = self.minute + self.extraMin
        if self.total_min > 60:
            self.total_min= self.total_min - 60
            self.total_hour += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.total_hour)+" hours, "+str(self.total_min)+" minutes "


    def __add__(self, other): #Brad suggested the if statement to get this part to work
        if isinstance(other,int):
            newHour = self.total_hour + other
            newMinute = self.total_min
            return Time(newHour,newMinute)

        else:
            newHour = self.total_hour + other.total_hour
            newMinute = self.total_min  + other.total_min
            return Time(newHour,newMinute)

def main():
    time0= Time()
    print(time0)
    time1 = Time(6)
    print(time1)
    time2 = Time(3,30)
    print(time2)
    time3 = Time(30,75)
    print(time3)
    time4 = Time(3.5)
    print(time4)
    print(time3 + time4)
    print(time3)
    print(time1 + 10)
    print(.75 + time2)

main()
```

Comment: Read the Python docs about the `__radd__` method.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785417/how-to-properly-overload-the-add-method help? Also, think carefully about how the conditional logic in your `__add__` method will react to a float.

Comment: @MichaelButscherthat was definitely it! One of those thats so easy you totally forget. Thanks so much