# Made a class of Point in python but I'm not quite sure what i did wrong

Tags: python, python-3.8

```
#
class Point:

def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def __add__(self, x, y):
    return self.x + self.y

def __sub__(self, x, y):
    return self.x - self.y

p1 = Point(1, 2)
p2 = Point(3, 4)
p3 = p1 + p2

print(p3)
```

OUTPUT: 
I get an an output which is looking for the parameter of y but i think i already pass y to it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:##################################", line 18, in <module>
    p3 = p1 + p2
TypeError: __add__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly overload the \_\_add\_\_ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785417/how-to-properly-overload-the-add-method)

Answer (score 3):

The expression `p3 = p1 + p2` is in reality executed as:

```
p3 = p1.__add__(p2)
```

With your current function signature `__add__(self, x, y)`, the Python interpreter will only receive `self` (`p1`), `x` (`p2`), but will be missing one argument (`y`), hence the error:

```
__add__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

What you need instead, is an `__add__` implementation (same goes for sub) which takes self and another point instance as arguments, and returns a new point:

```
class Point(object):
    def __add__(self, other: "Point") -> "Point":
        # returns a new point created by adding coordinates 
        # from self and the other point
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to indent the functions belonging to the class. Currently, Python thinks `__add__` function has nothing to do with `Point` and has two arguments `self` and `y`. If it was indented, `self` would automatically be set to a reference to the instance.

The second issue is, in built-in magic methods, you only pass a reference to the other object explicitly and access the attributes of the calling object via `self` by the automatic referencing I mentioned.

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
```