# Is there a way to redefine a built-in class in python?

Tags: python

Is there a way that you can redefine built-in classes in python (eg int). When I just do `class int` then the type is `__main__.int` not `int`, is there any way to define it without the `__main__`?

Comment: What would you want the effect of this to be?

Comment: Sure, you can do `int = float`, but what's the point? This seems to be a so-called "xy problem". In other words, you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: I don't really know, I was just wondering if there was any way to do it, possibly being able to edit how two ints interact, like changing what + or - do to two numbers

Comment: Much of that is compiled into the interpreter, so you can't change it.

Comment: [how-to-properly-overload-the-add-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785417/how-to-properly-overload-the-add-method) for classes that want an "add-like" functionality

Comment: @PatrickArtner That's for adding the method to user-defined classes, not changing how built-in classes work.

Comment: @Barmar hence the _for classes that want an "add-like" functionality_ ...

Comment: I tried to overload the built-in `__radd__` function of int and it raised this error:
`TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'int'`
It looks like they have custom exceptions for when someone attempts to do something like this.

Comment: @Barmar [never say never](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit). It is *possible*, although, IMO, highly highly inadvisable.

Comment: @RyanNygard you mean *assign to*, not overload. But yeah, dynamically modifying built-in classes is not supported. Although it is possible if you are willing to play around knowing the implementations details and other black magics.

Comment: This should probably be a dupilcate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192649/can-you-monkey-patch-methods-on-core-types-in-python

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Which presumably means it will be implementation-dependent changes, not portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think thats possible without editing python source written in c
but you can inherit from the built in classes like `int` then add your methods like:

```
class MyList(list):
    def sumOfAll(self):
        return sum(self)
myList = MyList([1,2,3])
print(myList.sumOfAll())
```

Output : `6`

Comment: Ok, I was assuming it wasn't possible but just wanted to check, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It is *possible* without editing the source, but not advisable.